# How to wrap an element in a html string var?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I use the following code:

```
var output = '<div class="info"><span class="bus-number">468 (58247)</span></div>';
var span = $(output).find('span.bus-number').text();
console.log(span);
```

I can see the value

> *468 (58247)*

in the console, but if I try to use the [wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) method with the following code:

```
var output = '<div class="info"><span class="bus-number">468 (58247)</span></div>';
$(output).find('span.bus-number').wrap('<b></b>');
console.log(output);
```

I can't obtain this html code:

```
<div class="info"><b><span class="bus-number">468 (58247)</span></b></div>
```

How can I obtain the string with the wrapped element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not updating the string just updating the jQuery object so grab HTML content from jQuery object using **[`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** method.

```js
var output = '<div class="info"><span class="bus-number">468 (58247)</span></div>';
// create a div element with html content
output = $('<div/>', {
    html: output
      // get span
  }).find('span.bus-number')
  // wrap the span
  .wrap('<b></b>')
  // back to previous selector
  .end()
  // get the html content
  .html();

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Or use **[`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)** property of dom element.

```js
var output = '<div class="info"><span class="bus-number">468 (58247)</span></div>';
// create jQuery object
output = $(output)
  // get span element
  .find('span.bus-number')
  // wrap span with b
  .wrap('<b></b>')
  // back to previous selector and get dom object
  // using [0] after get html content from dom
  .end()[0].outerHTML;

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer : glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `html()` function.

Note that the `html()` function returns the INNER html of the element, so you need to wrap it with another element to get the html:

```js
var output = '<div class="info"><span class="bus-number">468 (58247)</span></div>';
var span = $(output).find('span.bus-number').text();
console.log(span);

var span = $(output).find('span.bus-number').wrap('<b></b>');
console.log(span.parent('b').html());
console.log(span.parents('div.info').html());
console.log($('<div>').append(span.parents('div.info')).html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `output` is just a string which is immutable.
For example you can do

```
var output = '<div class="info"><span class="bus-number">468 (58247)</span></div>';
$output = $(output);
$output.find('span.bus-number').wrap('<b></b>');
console.log($output.text());
```